# Pass a class that follows a given protocol into a method and then instantiate the class using swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm looking to create a very generic service layer that looks to call Alamofire. See code:

```
func getRequest(from endpoint:String!, withParameters parameters:[String:Any]?,withModel model:RuutsBaseResponse, andCompleteWith handler:@escaping (RuutsBaseResponse?, NSError?) -> ()){

        func generateModel(withResponse result:NSDictionary?, withError error:NSError?) -> (){
            handler(model.init(fromDictionary: result),error);
        }

        alamoFireService.AlamoFireServiceRequest(endpoint:endpoint, httpVerb:.get, parameters:parameters!, completionHandler:generateModel);
    }
```

This is what the RuutsBaseResponse looks like:

```
protocol RuutsBaseResponse {
    init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary);
}
```

The `getRequest` looks to do the following:

1. Taken in any class so long as it conforms to `RuutsBaseResponse` protocol.
2. Make a service call using alamoFire using the parameters passed into it.
3. alamoFire will call the generateModel method once the service call is completed.
4. When it calls the `generateModel` the method is supposed to instantiate the model and pass into it the Dictionary received from alamoFire.

The issue is the model, i'm struggling to achieve the requirements above. I keep getting:

> Error:(22, 21) 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to
>   initialize a new object of the same dynamic type

All I'm looking to do is make a layer generic enough to make a service call and create an object/model that is created from the Dictionary passed back from alamoFire.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to use [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179):

```
protocol RuutsBaseResponse {
    init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary);
}

struct BaseModel: RuutsBaseResponse {
    internal init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        print("instantiated BaseModel")
    }
}

struct SecondaryModel: RuutsBaseResponse {
    internal init(fromDictionary dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        print("instantiated SecondaryModel")
    }
}

// state that this function handles generics that conform to the RuutsBaseResponse 
// protocol
func getRequest<T: RuutsBaseResponse>(handler: (_ response: T) -> ()) {
    handler(T(fromDictionary: NSDictionary()))
}

getRequest(handler: { model in
    // will print 'instantiated BaseModel'
    (model as! BaseModel)
})

getRequest(handler: { model in
    // will print 'instantiated SecondaryModel'
    (model as! SecondaryModel)
})
```